# Comparator in binary search

Tags: binary-search, comparator

I am not sure how to write comparator for Collectionos.binarySearch(). Can anyone help ? sample code:

```
List<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<>();

List<List<Object>> list2 = new ArrayList<>();


//loop starts
// adds elements into list1
```

`list1.add(values);`//values is an object containing elements like [3, John, Smith]

```
if (list2.size() == 0) {
    list2.add(list1);//first element
} else {
    if (index >= 0)  {
   int index = Collections.binarySearch(list2, list1, comparator);
    list2.add(index, list1);//I want to add these elements in ascending order ?
} 
}
```

`//loop ends`

How do I write comparator, so that elements in list 2 are added in ascending or descending order.

Comment: That depends, how do you want the lists to be sorted? According to length? Sum of contents? ...?

Comment: @Martin sum of contents

Comment: Then you must decide how "3", "John" and "Smith" should be summed, then implement that in Happy's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous class which implements a `Comparator<List<Object>>`:

```java
int index = Collections.binarySearch(list2, list1, new Comparator<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(List<Object> o1, List<Object> o2) {
        // Your implementation here
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an [`IComparer<List<Object>>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or use a lambda expression.

Comment: I can't recall java having a ICompare class, you're thinking of C#. Java has the Comparable interface or a Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a class that implements the Comparator interface.

For example, you can do this inline with an anonymous class:

```
Comparator<List<Object>> comparator = new Comparator<List<Object>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(List<Object> x, List<Object> y) { 
        // custom logic to compare x and y here. Return a negative number
        // if x < y, a positive number if x > y, and 0 otherwise
    }

};
Collections.binarySearch(list, comparator);
```